# How to make Virtual Machine assignment more efficient?

Tags: python-2.7, cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

I was working on this project that aim to make VM assignment more efficient.

By VM assigment, what I mean is as soon as a request for new virtual machine creation comes to the Openstack platform how the platform handles the request. In the openstack framework, nova-scheduler does this part. I was looking to add more features/filters into the nova scheduler.

I wanted to implement some special kinds of filters, in the Nova scheduler. That would have some special rules or which would maintain averaged load across the whole system and saving energy. Generally, A system with medium load consumes less energy than a system running at maximum load. I was thinking of filters that  would allocate Virtual machines close, ie on a same rack. When a request for making a cluster of Vm is recieved. I would like what you think of feasiblity of any such filters. And How effective they can be ?

Any Help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: Well that's a lot of questions in one single question..
What have you tried...so far..

Comment: I have gone throught the documentation and code for the Nova Scheduler. @http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/config-reference/content/section_compute-scheduler.html ,the documentation is quite self explanatory. But the problem is in identification of acutal feasiblity of implementations custom filters.

Comment: @adil, think I should edit my inital question.

Comment: Yes try to make it specific....and try to ask in steps :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, openstack assign vms to bare metal whose memory is larger.

```
scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.multi.MultiScheduler
scheduler_driver_task_period=60
compute_scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler.FilterScheduler
scheduler_available_filters=nova.scheduler.filters.all_filters
scheduler_default_filters=RetryFilter,AvailabilityZoneFilter,RamFilter,ComputeFilter,ComputeCapabilitiesFilter,ImagePropertiesFilter,ServerGroupAntiAffinityFilter,ServerGroupAffinityFilter
```

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/config-reference/content/section_compute-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I am thinking for creating a new filter.